# how to generate allure reports using page-object and watir

Tags: ruby, selenium, watir, allure, page-object-gem

I have used the configuration mentioned in the allure-ruby-commons in the below link

https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-ruby/tree/master/allure-ruby-commons

But am unable to generate allure reports using the same. Can any one please help me on that.

How to generate allure reports using watir and page-object gem

```
require 'watir'
require 'page-object'

class GithubPage
    include PageObject

    link(:sign_in, text: /Sign in/)
    text_field(:user_id, id: 'login_field')
    text_field(:password, id: 'password')
    button(:login_btn, value: 'Sign in')
    link(:notification, href: '/notifications')
    list_items(:name_count, xpath: "//p[text()='Repositories']/following-sibling::ul/li")
    span(:select_all, text: /Select all/)
    button(:select_remaining, text: /Select all/)
    button(:done_all, css: "div[class*='notifications-mark-all-actions'] button[title='Done']")
    button(:done, css: "div[class*='notifications-mark-selected-actions'] button[title='Done']")
    h3(:no_notifications, text: 'All caught up!')

    def login(username, password)
        sign_in
        self.user_id = username
        self.password = password
        login_btn
    end

    def check_and_read_notifications
        notification_element.when_visible.click
        if no_notifications?
            puts 'There are no Notifications left'
        else
            name_count_elements.each do |name|
                puts name.text
            end
            select_all_element.click
            if select_remaining?
                select_remaining
                done_all
            else
                done
            end
            sleep 1
            notification
        end
    end

end
```

```
require_relative 'github_page.rb'
require 'allure-ruby-commons'

browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, headless: true
browser.window.resize_to(1920, 1080)
github = GithubPage.new(browser)

github.navigate_to 'http://github.com'
github.login('test', 'tester')
github.check_and_read_notifications

Allure.configuration

Allure.configure do |config|
    config.results_directory = "./Results"
    config.clean_results_directory = true
    config.logging_level = Logger::INFO
end
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Allure, so sorry if this is an irrelevant question, but what are you wanting to report on? From the documentation, it sounds like there are 2 use cases: (1) generating reports from test frameworks or (2) tracking method calls of a class. What information you want to gather likely impacts what code needs to be implemented.

Comment: am trying for first option

Comment: Are you trying to create your test framework? Otherwise, there's a specific gem for `allure-rspec` and `allure-cucumber`.

Comment: @JustinKo am able to generate reports using allure-cucumber but i need to generate it using plain page-object gem